# Perl: undef element in array

Tags: perl

I defined some elements in an array:

```
my @arrTest;
$arrTest[0]=1;
$arrTest[2]=2;

#Result for @arrTest is: (1, undef, 2)


if($arrTest[1]==0)
{
    print "one\n";
}
elsif($arrTest[1] == undef)
{
    print "undef\n";
}
```

I think it should print "undef". But it prints "one" here...

Does it mean $arrTest[1]=undef=0?

How can I modify the "if condition" to distinguish the "undef" in array element?

Comment: Read documentation for [defined](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined) -- change your code to `elsif( ! defined($arrTest[1]) ) {`

Answer (score 7):

The operator `==` in the code `$arrTest[1] == 0` puts `$arrTest[1]` in [numeric context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop) and so its value gets converted to a number if needed, as best as the interpreter can do, and that is used in the comparison.  And when a variable in a numeric test hasn't been defined a `0` is used so the test evaluates to true (the variable stays `undef`).

Most of the time when this need be done we get to hear about it (there are some exceptions) -- if we have `use warnings;` that is (best at the beginning of the program)<sup>†</sup>  Please always have [warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings) on, and use [strict](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict). They directly help.

To test for defined-ness there is [defined](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined)

```
if (not defined $arrTest[1]) { ... }
```

---

<sup>†</sup> A  demo

```
perl -wE'say "zero" if $v == 0; say $v; ++$v; say $v'
```

The [-w](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-w) enables warnings. This command-line program prints

```
Use of uninitialized value $v in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
zero
Use of uninitialized value $v in say at -e line 1.

1
```

Note how `++` doesn't warn, one of the mentioned exceptions.

Comment: *Every* Perl script should have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` as the first two lines. The *only* acceptable situation to omit those is when working with extremely legacy code that doesn't follow strict guidelines.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes, thank you, and I never get tired of posting that ... still editing and will work in that `strict` as well (which has _nothing_ to do with this question so it's not clear how best to weave it in)

Comment: Can I ask one more question? How can I distinguish if an array is empty?

Comment: @blueFish "_distinguish if an array is empty?_"  -- For that we can simply test for truth, `if (@ary)` (it has something), or `if (not @ary)` (empty).  Note that `if (@ary)` is true even if the array has an element which is `undef` or an empty string.  It  tests whether there is _anything_ in it

Comment: @blueFish  "_Can I ask one more question?_"  -- yes please, all you need :)  I hope that this post answered your original question (as posted) but please ask whatever else needs clarification.  (I'll let you know if I feel that you'd better ask a separate question, or if it just can't be answered in a skinny comment, etc)